# TYPO3 felogin feuser registration hook

Tags: typo3

I need your help.

There are felogin available hooks list:

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['beforeRedirect' ]`

Receives loginType and redirectUrl as parameters, allows to change the redirectUrl

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['postProcContent ']`

Postprocessing of the output just before it is returned

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['login_confirme d']`

Hook for general actions after login has been confirmed

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['loginFormOnSubm itFuncs']`

This Hook is used by kb_md5fepw extension to set hidden fields and onsubmit-scripts

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['logout_confirm ed']`

Hook for general actions after logout has been confirmed

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['forgotPasswordM ail ']`

Hook to change the contents of the forgot password mail

But I need hook after new user was registered. Can somebody help me ?

May be exists some way to fix my problem ? Or may be I can redeclare felogin controller and extend it ? Tell me please how I can do it ?

Comment: which typo3 version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a hook that occurs right after user authentication instead:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_userauth.php']['postUserLookUp']
```

and check if the user has previously logged in (by checking lastlogin in fe_users). I am not complete sure about the timing though, meaning the field lastlogin could already be set at this point.